# Using webkitdirectory with CakePHP forms

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, webkit

I am trying to upload a whole folder with my form, which from some Google research I have found is possible with 'webkitdirectory'. However there seems to be very little help about how I add this option to my CakePHP form which the site is built in?

I think what I might have to do, if they insist on whole folder uploads (which I think are not a good idea on a website). Is to built is using a standard html form and not built it using the CakePHP helpers?

Any ideas on how I might do this?

If not it could be something that could be added in the a new CakePHP version!

Many thanks

Glenn.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form` helper should be capable of creating an appropriate input field. Here's some example code:

```php
echo $this->Form->input('file', array
(
    'type' => 'file',
    'name' => 'data[Model][file][]',

    // would work too, but the file data would then
    // be found in CakeRequest::$params['form']
    // 'name' => 'file[]',

    'multiple' => true,
    'webkitdirectory' => 'webkitdirectory'
));
```

it would create the following HTML:

```
<div class="input file">
    <label for="ModelFile">File</label>
    <input type="file" name="data[Model][file][]" multiple="multiple" webkitdirectory="webkitdirectory" id="ModelFile"/>
</div>
```

Note the use of `'webkitdirectory' => 'webkitdirectory'`, this is necessary as the `Form` helper doesn't recognize `webkitdirectory` it as a boolean attribute, ie using `true` would cause the generated attributes value to be `1`, which works, but is AFAIK actually invalid.

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::input

Comment: Many thanks, I was, after giving it some thought whether I should try something like that! I try it later and let you know. Also just as a side note, I am not sure about doing this? As its only webkit supported. If a user tried this with IE for example, would that give cake / general PHP any issues? Or would it simple not work in IE?

Comment: @GlennCurtis There won't be any general CakePHP/PHP issues, user-agents that do not support these features will continue to supply the default file upload functionality.